# converting time from utc to device timezone and add 9 minute

Tags: android, date, datetime

I am having some doubts regarding the conversion of time from utc to device time zone.I am getting date from Server and that is in UTC. I convert that corresponding Time to my device Time zone. But my device time is Showing 10 minutes backwards. My requirement is that I need to add 9 minutes to my Device Time Zone. So if anyone knows the answer..please do help

```
 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
 df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

 Date timestamp = new Date();
 timestamp = df.parse(s);

 df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
 date.setText(tk.nextToken());
```

Comment: fix the date on your device. also on your server.

Comment: but the date on my device is correct

Comment: is it possible to add 10 minutes to the correspponding time